# Factorials with for loops in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, factorial

My question is about factorials as I get very confused with them. I understand the cin, and the for loop, also the cout and stuff, however, I get very confused when it comes to multiplying the past values, what I mean is this: For instance factorial 5! = 1*2*3*4*5, I don't understand how the code stores the past values and multiply, for example, 1 first, 1*2 = 2 second, 1*2*3 = 6 third and so on. Can someone please explain this to me. Thank You.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

    int main () { 
     int sayi; 
        cout<< "sayi: "; 
        cin>> sayi; 
        // 5! = 5*4*3*2*1 faktoryaller 
        int faktoriyel = 1; 
        for(int i = 1; i <= sayi; i++){
            faktoriyel = faktoriyel * i;
            cout<<faktoriyel<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"Faktoriyel: "<<faktoriyel<<endl;

    int gir; { 
        cout<<"sayi giriniz: "; 
        cin>> gir; 
        int faktoriyel = 1; 
        for(int i = 1; i <= gir; i++) { 
            faktoriyel = faktoriyel * gir; 
            cout<<faktoriyel<<endl;
        } 
         cout<<"Faktoriyel: "<< faktoriyel <<endl; 
        }
        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: Please explain in detail step by step. Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `faktoriyel = faktoriyel * i;` This is how the program stores the intermediate values, `=` means assignment, i.e. evaluate what is on the right hand side and store it in the variable on the left hand side. `=` doesn't mean equals which confuses some people.

Comment: @YavuzBozkurt "_Please explain in detail step by step. Thank You_" Did you try using the debugger? With debugger, you can step through your program, step-by-step, on your own..

Comment: Thank you for the comments, yes, I think I will be teaching myself how to use the debugger soon as well.

Answer (score 0):

If `i` is set to 5, the code in this loop will be exectured 5 times:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= gir; i++) { 
    faktoriyel = faktoriyel * gir; 
    cout<<faktoriyel<<endl;
}
```

The first time `faktoriyel = faktoriyel * gir;` will be executed, `faktoriyel` and `i` will be 1, so, you can see the line as:

```
faktoriyel = 1 * 1;
```

So, `faktoriyel` stays 1. The second time the line is executed, you can read it as follow, because, now, `i` is 2:

```
faktoriyel = 1 * 2;
```

So, `faktoriyel` becomes 2. So, as a last example, the third time round, the line is the same as: (because `faktoriyel` is now 2 and `i` is 3)

```
faktoriyel = 2 * 3;
```

Something that is confusing for people with math background is that `=` is an assignment operator. It does change the value on the left. It doesn't state mathematical equality. Also, variables have states and change over time. It's not easy (at first) to switch from this paradigm to the usual mathematical paradigm you see in formal proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Let's unroll what happens in your code :

- `fakt = 1`
- loop `i = 1 | fakt = 1`

  - `fakt = fakt * i` <==> `fakt = 1 * 1` <==> `fakt = 1`
- loop `i = 2 | fakt = 1`

  - `fakt = fakt * i` <==> `fakt = 1 * 2` <==> `fakt = 2`
- loop `i = 3 | fakt = 2`

  - `fakt = fakt * i` <==> `fakt = 2 * 3` <==> `fakt = 6`
- loop `i = 4 | fakt = 6`

  - `fakt = fakt * i` <==> `fakt = 3 * 4` <==> `fakt = 12`
- loop `i = 5 | fakt = 12`

  - `fakt = fakt * i` <==> `fakt = 12 * 5` <==> `fakt = 60`

the program doesn't store that it has to do multiple multiplication, it does it on the run.

You could take a look at [recursive factorial](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/factorial-recursion) that may be a little easier to understand

Comment: Thank you for your comment, It really helped me understand, I see how it works now. It is step by step which is very good!

Comment: thinking "step by step" is really one of the best attitude to have, either for debugging or understanding code!